How to replace a word to another word in a list python
If I have this list:
['hello world', 'latest.png', 'have a good day', 'stack overflow', 'the best'  
 'latest .png', 'i believe somebody will help me', 'latest.png', 'latest.png']

Is it possible to change the first latest.png to  latest1.png the next latest.png to latest2.png, etc. ?
Is there any elegant way for this?   thanks a lot

Yes, it's possible, why wouldn't it? Use a counter variable to hold the current number to append. Loop through the list, if it's latest.png replace it with the name with the current counter, and increment the counter.

Don't worry about doing it "elegantly". It's only 3-4 lines of code, anything that works should be fine.

@Barmar's comment explains it well.
Assuming that words is your list, your code would look something like this:
latest_count = 1
new_words = []

for word in words:
    if word == "latest.png":
        new_words.append(f"latest{latest_count}.png")
        latest_count += 1
    else:
        new_words.append(word)

new_words will contain your updated list and you will still have your original list.

def replace_repetitions(my_list):
    new_list = []
    word_counts = {}
    for word in my_list:
        base_word, extension = split_with_extension(word)
        if base_word in word_counts:
            count = word_counts[base_word] + 1
            word_counts[base_word] = count
            new_list.append(f"{base_word}{count}{extension}")
        else:
            word_counts[base_word] = 1
            new_list.append(word)
    return new_list

def split_with_extension(word):
    parts = word.rsplit(".", 1)
    if len(parts) == 1:
        return word, ""
    else:
        return parts[0], "." + parts[1]

trial = ['hello world', 'latest.png', 'have a good day', 'stack overflow', 'the best', 'latest.png',
     'i believe somebody will help me', 'latest.png', 'latest.png', 'the best']
print(replace_repetitions(trial))

This will help you with scenario as well as it will take care if you have a filename with extension in list. This is generic so it will also work if you have any other word that is repeated in list.
Example in below output latest.png as well aas the best is repeated:
['hello world', 'latest.png', 'have a good day', 'stack overflow', 'the best', 'latest2.png', 'i believe somebody will help me', 'latest3.png', 'latest4.png', 'the best2']

If you want to do this for a specific word only like for example avoid the best and only consider latest.png then add if condition in for loop

The easiest way would be to check if the word is "latest.png" and keep a counter.
c = 1 
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] == 'latest.png':
        x[i] = f"latest{c}.png"
        c += 1

This should change your every "latest.png" to counter value i.e "latest1.png" and so on.

Try something like this:
lst = ['hello world', 'latest.png', 'have a good day', 'stack overflow', 'the best'  
 'latest .png', 'i believe somebody will help me', 'latest.png', 'latest.png']

num_latest = 1

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if (lst[i] == 'latest.png'):
        temp = lst[i].split('.')
        lst[i] = temp[0] + str(num_latest) + '.' + temp[1]
        num_latest = num_latest + 1

print(lst)

The output:
['hello world', 'latest1.png', 'have a good day', 'stack overflow', 'the bestlatest .png', 'i believe somebody will help me', 'latest2.png', 'latest3.png']

